# Laravel + Crontab not working

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

I am trying to set up scheduler in Laravel.

Here is my crontab which I debugged and works fine - atleast with my cron job

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "foobar" >> /my_path/example.txt
```

I don't know if this one works:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/myproject/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is my schedule function in Kernel:

```
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('inspire')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }
```

When I am in my project and try `php artisan inspire` it actually works, so I expected it to fire every minute, but it won't do anything. Nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does inspire do for you? Doesn't it just echo an inspiring quote? There is no way you will see this quote appear in your terminal unless you write the output away somewhere.

Comment: @Jerodev Oh, I though it should show the quote just like when I enter php artisan inspire. Is there any way to check if the crontab is installed correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This part just puts the output into oblivion so you'll never see it:

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Why not try:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/myproject/artisan schedule:run >> /my_path/example.txt
```

And check to see if the cron is run in **/my_path/example.txt**

The default inspire command essentially just echo's a quote so the only way to see it in a cron is to output it to a file on the server.

You can do this using something similar to this:

```
$schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```

Further details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#task-output

Comment: tried this one. example.txt contains: Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' inspire > '/dev/null' 2>&1

Comment: This show's it is working correctly, next you can try outputing it to a specific file: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#task-output using $schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($filePath); or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

you should try something

**like * * * * *  cd /Path/TO/YOUR_PROJECT/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**

Answer (score 3):

in my case, I had to explicity a php version compatible with laravel, in my cron job:

```
cd /path/to/my/project && /usr/local/bin/ea-php71 artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Am also using laravel 4.2, Here is my Cron command which currently working good.

```
0   0   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /*****/******/public_html/artisan command:firemyevent
```

Hope It will help you.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php` solved the issue to run inside docker container!

Answer (score 2):

I made it run in mac through:

```
 * * * * * cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rcraze && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

You have to put full path of PHP (you can get it through `whereis php` command in MAC terminal) and pull path of your project.